# loading page specific javascript before angular in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs

I'm working on a Rails/Angular app.  There are theme specific folders under `app/themes` which are added to the asset pipeline.

**config/initializers/assets.rb**

```
Dir[Rails.root.join("app", "themes", "*")].each do |path|
  %w{stylesheets javascripts images fonts}.each do |type|
    theme_assets = File.join(path, type)
    Rails.application.config.assets.paths << theme_assets
  end
  theme_folder = File.basename(path)
  Dir["#{path}/images/*"].each do |img|
    Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += [ File.basename(img) ]
  end
  Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += [ "#{theme_folder}/index.css",
                                                  "#{theme_folder}/index.js" ]
end
```

There's also

```
Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += ["angular_vendor.js"]
```

which loads angular from `app/assets/javascripts`

The page specific javascript in `app/themes/#{theme_folder}` gets loaded before angular does.

I have some angular code I want to run in this page specific javascript.  So I need it to load after the angular does.

Comment: Have you tried to add `Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += "angular_vendor.js"` to `config/initializers/assets.rb`

Comment: Or another way could be: `Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w( angular_vendor.js )`

Comment: It already is in `config/initializers/assets.rb` and it is in array form.

Answer (score 0):

The code does not have to be run when it is loaded (depending on how you wrote it). You can trigger it on an event, for example on document ready.

I don't know if this is applicable to your use case, but perhaps you could encapsulate it like this:

```
var MyCode = (function () {
  function myFunc(){
  }

  function myFunc2(){
  }

  return {
    myFunc: myFunc,
    myFunc2: myFunc2
  }
}());

$(document).on('ready', function () {
  MyCode.myFunc();
  MyCode.myFunc2();
});
```